# Why do you use return number?

Tags: javascript

I am a bit confused about this code, mainly the return function. I understand it takes the two parameters given and then multiplies them, but I don't know why or how the function number represents 5 in this case, and how it knows to multiply.

Everyone has been so helpful, I now understand what higher-order and realized it is just the arrow function that is making me confused. I need to try and understand them a little bit more.

```js
function multiplier(factor) {
    return number => number * factor;
}

let twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));
```

Comment: `multiplier` is a higher-order function - it's a function that *returns a function*. For whatever reason the outer function is a regular function (`function (arg) { return thing }`) and the inner function is an arrow function (`arg => thing`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do you use return number?

Well it's not the variable `number` which is returned, but a function instead, if you are not familiar with ES6 arrow functions syntax then here is the same using the old syntax, it is clear now what's going on right?

```js
function multiplier(factor) {
  return function(number) {
    return number * factor;
  }
}

let twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));
```

Comment: So it takes the third line and can pretty much condense it down to another line in a different form of syntax?

Comment: I don't seem to understand your comment?! what do you mean

Answer (score 3):

> A function that returns a function is called a [Higher-Order Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function)

the high-order function `multiplier()` accepts a single parameter `factor`, and returns a new ([arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) function.

the new function accepts a single parameter `number`, and returns the multiplication of `factor` with the `number`.

the returned function can access the `factor` argument due to the closure.